# Include post title in readmore link?

Tags: excerpt

Trying to include the post title in my excerpt readmore links. I've read the codex on this, but my theme files are much more complicated so I could use a bit of expert help...

Extract from functions.php: ** Edited to show more code.........

```
function theme_get_content($args = array()) {

$more_tag = theme_get_array_value($args, 'more_tag', __('Continue Bob <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', THEME_NS));
theme_ob_start();
the_content($more_tag);
$content = theme_ob_get_clean();
return $content . wp_link_pages(array(
            'before' => '<p><span class="page-navi-outer page-navi-caption"><span class="page-navi-inner">' . __('Pages', THEME_NS) . ': </span></span>',
            'after' => '</p>',
            'link_before' => '<span class="page-navi-outer"><span class="page-navi-inner">',
            'link_after' => '</span></span>',
            'echo' => 0
        ));
```

}

```
function theme_get_excerpt($args = array()) {
global $post;
$more_tag = theme_get_array_value($args, 'more_tag', __('My Words...<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', THEME_NS));
$auto = theme_get_array_value($args, 'auto', theme_get_option('theme_metadata_excerpt_auto'));
$all_words = theme_get_array_value($args, 'all_words', theme_get_option('theme_metadata_excerpt_words'));
$min_remainder = theme_get_array_value($args, 'min_remainder', theme_get_option('theme_metadata_excerpt_min_remainder'));
$allowed_tags = theme_get_array_value($args, 'allowed_tags',
    (theme_get_option('theme_metadata_excerpt_use_tag_filter')
        ? explode(',',str_replace(' ', '', theme_get_option('theme_metadata_excerpt_allowed_tags')))
        : null));
$perma_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
$more_token = '%%theme_more%%';
$show_more_tag = false;
$tag_disbalance = false;
if (post_password_required($post)) {
    return get_the_excerpt();
}
if ($auto && has_excerpt($post->ID)) {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

    $show_more_tag = theme_strlen($post->post_content) > 0;
} else {
    $excerpt = get_the_content($more_token);
    // hack for badly written plugins
    theme_ob_start();
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
    $excerpt = theme_ob_get_clean();
    global $multipage;
    if ($multipage && theme_strpos($excerpt, $more_token) === false) {
        $show_more_tag = true;
    }
    if (theme_is_empty_html($excerpt))
        return $excerpt;
    if ($allowed_tags !== null) {
        $allowed_tags = '<' . implode('><', $allowed_tags) . '>';
        $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt, $allowed_tags);
    }
    if (theme_strpos($excerpt, $more_token) !== false) {
        $excerpt = str_replace($more_token, $more_tag, $excerpt);
    } elseif ($auto && is_numeric($all_words)) {
        $token = "%theme_tag_token%";
        $content_parts = explode($token, str_replace(array('<', '>'), array($token . '<', '>' . $token), $excerpt));
        $content = array();
        $word_count = 0;
        foreach ($content_parts as $part) {
            if (theme_strpos($part, '<') !== false || theme_strpos($part, '>') !== false) {
                $content[] = array('type' => 'tag', 'content' => $part);
            } else {
                $all_chunks = preg_split('/([\s])/u', $part, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                foreach ($all_chunks as $chunk) {
                    if ('' != trim($chunk)) {
                        $content[] = array('type' => 'word', 'content' => $chunk);
                        $word_count += 1;
                    } elseif ($chunk != '') {
                        $content[] = array('type' => 'space', 'content' => $chunk);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (($all_words < $word_count) && ($all_words + $min_remainder) <= $word_count) {
            $show_more_tag = true;
            $tag_disbalance = true;
            $current_count = 0;
            $excerpt = '';
            foreach ($content as $node) {
                if ($node['type'] == 'word') {
                    $current_count++;
                }
                $excerpt .= $node['content'];
                if ($current_count == $all_words) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            $excerpt .= '&hellip;'; // ...
        }
    }
}


if ($show_more_tag) {
    $excerpt = $excerpt . ' <a class="more-link" href="' . $perma_link . '">' . $more_tag . ' </a>';
```

}

```
if ($tag_disbalance) {
    $excerpt = force_balance_tags($excerpt);
}
return $excerpt;
```

}

Any ideas how to include the post title within the readmore permalink???
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following code is in-fact the code that is controlling your read more link then you perhaps the following may work;

```
if ($show_more_tag) {
    global $post;
    $excerpt = $excerpt . ' <a class="more-link" href="' . $perma_link . '">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . ' </a>';
}
```

I've declared `global $post;` again, just in case the above call to the conditional statement above is built outside of the initial `$post` shown in your first snippet; because you haven't provided the full code to assess.

But try the above and see if it has any effect and let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried adding this to my functions.php but it did not make any difference I'm afraid. But thankyou for trying.

I didn't post the whole excerpt section as I was concerned it was too big, will edit my question if it is required

Comment: Scrub that. Posting the rest of the comment I realised you probably meant me to replace the exisitng if show more tag bit with your version - BINGO! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Yup, that's right... :) Glad it's working! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the read more link with the `the_content_more_link` filter.

```
function the_content_more_link_wpse_100990($more) {
  global $post;
  $pattern = '|>([^<]+)<|';
  return preg_replace($pattern,">$1{$post->post_title} <",$more,1);
}   
add_filter('the_content_more_link','the_content_more_link_wpse_100990');
```

I'd probably do some error checking if I were to put that into production but that is the idea.

Comment: Hey s_ha_dum - Thanks for the suggestion. I added your filter to the end of my functions.php file, but I'm afraid it didn't do anything. But never mind, it's probably something stupid I did wrong. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It will only work for a `more` tag generated by WordPress, or other, functions that run the `the_content_more_link` filter.